# Spring MVC controller executes task asynchronously in Servlet 2.5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, asynchronous, concurrency, runnable

I am working on a Spring MVC application on Java 6 JVM running in a Servlet 2.5 (Tomcat) environment. I need to develop a controller method that will perform a long running task (large database query, generate report and deliver email to user). Justifiably, I want the task to run asynchronously. When I searched around, I found a lot of articles that were based on Servlet 3 and AsyncTask which I understand is not supported by my environment.

- Can I use one of Java's executors (e.g. `ExecutorService`/`NewFixedThreadPool`) to execute a `Runnable` task from the controller method, so as to return from the method immediately while the task is progressing asynchronously?
- How do I ensure that the executor is shutdown gracefully along with the web application?
- Is there a Spring based executor I can use that somehow has access to all the auto-wired dependencies, rather than me creating `final` references to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use one of Java's executors (e.g. ExecutorService/NewFixedThreadPool) to execute a Runnable task from the controller method

Yes, you can. But since you're using Spring MVC, you could simply use its [asynchronous method support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-async).

> How do I ensure that the executor is shutdown gracefully along with the web application?

You can register a ServletContextListener that shuts down the pool when the application is being destroyed. But if you use Spring's Async support, it will destroy theassociated executor automatically when the context is destroyed.

> Is there a Spring based executor I can use that somehow has access to all the auto-wired dependencies

Async methods are Spring bean methods, and have access to the autowired dependencies of the bean they belong to.

Comment: Nizel, can I annotate any method including controller methods with `@Async`? Looking at the link you provided, it appears so, but I wanted to verify. Particularly so because I am using Servlet 2.5.

Comment: I don't think so, and that wouldn't make much sense. You want the request to be handled synchronously and provide a synchronous response. But when handling this request, you want to start an asynchronous task, and that is easily done by calling another Spring bean method annotated with `@Async`.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. True, what was I thinking about trying to make the request asynchronous?! I'll check this out first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has the @Async annotation that you might want to look into.